# Saving PHP array as javascript array variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am using the following pair of javascript and php files to get the names of all the image files in a directory.

Javascript

```
$(document).on("click", "ul#matchListUL li a", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var matchLst = $(this).attr('href');
      var filenames = new Array();
      if (matchLst !== null && matchLst !=="") {
        $.ajax({
            url : "filenames.php",
            dataType : "JSON",
            type : "POST",
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);  
            }
        });
        }
      return false;
    })
```

filename.php

```
$tardir = "mysite.com/projects/" . $seldir . "/" . $match . "/*.jpg" ;
$files = glob($tardir);

$fileName = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    $fileName = basename($num, ".jpg");

}
echo json_encode($fileName);
```

However, this just prints only one file name - essentially the last file in the folder.

How can i get all the filenames and can is save the filenames locally using local storage?

Comment: `$fileName[] = basename($num, ".jpg");`

Comment: @splash58 Thank you.

Comment: _"Thank you. Will accept your answer"_ - did you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you should do this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    // [] will add the value to the array
    $fileName[] = basename($num, ".jpg");

}
```

And instead of using a `for` loop to go through your array, use a `foreach` loop instead, like this:

```
foreach($files as $file){
    $fileName[] = basename($file, ".jpg");
}
```